# Copying set of records in Django

Tags: django, database

How do I copy the data from one record to another?
That is, I have the record

```
pk: 1,
name: "Regis"
total: "1000.00"
```

I wanted to create a new exactly the same record.

```
pk: 2,
name: "Regis"
total: "1000.00"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `pk` to `None` and save the record:

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
obj.pk = None
obj.save()
```

This is an [official method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances) of copying model instances.

Comment: and if contains relationship?

Comment: Foreign key relationship will be preserved. But related objects will not be copied - new object will have relations to the same objects as the old one.  And M2M relationship should be handled manually. See the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances